# Complex looping in python

Tags: python

I have a list of 1000 items and for each item I need to execute a calculation requiring a loop of 30 iterations. I would then like to create an array that compiles the result of each of the 30 iterations (ending with an array in the shape of 30x1000). Does anyone have any advice about the best way to do this in python?

Thank you!

Zack

Comment: Put the calculation in a function, then call the function using a list comprehension.

Comment: This is hardly complex looping.  Create a list with 30 empty lists and append to each of these sublist as you go through the 30 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

arr_init = np.ones(1000)

# your function
def iterations():
   return [i for i in range(30)]

# final array with 30 results per each value in arr_init
arr_final = np.array([np.array(iterations()) for i in arr_init]).T

print(arr_final.shape)

Out:
(30, 1000)
```